# it is advisable to use a LinkedList to send an object to the server?

Tags: java, linked-list, client-server

case with linkedlist:

```
private void send(Socket clientSocket, LinkedList<Person> person) {


        try {
             ObjectOutputStream output; 
             output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

             output.writeObject(person);


        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

case without linkedlist:

```
private void send(Socket clientSocket, Person person) {


            try {
                 ObjectOutputStream output; 
                 output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                 output.writeObject(person);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
```

I've seen a lot of source code where we use the linked list but I do not understand why.
are the same thing?  if not, what is the difference?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between Person and LinkedList is that Person is only one person, LinkedList is an ordered list of person, that is more than one person.

You should not use LinkedList if not in very specific cases, usually using List is enough, cause you're declaring the interface you need for the method to work, and not the specific implementation.

Once you have a method with List, whether you pass LinkedList or ArrayList or another implementation compliant to the List semantics, should be functionally equivalent and "only" offer better performances, either on inserts, or on retrieval, or on memory consumption.

However, these performance benefits are useful if you are doing very computationally intensive operations on the list, like looping a lot, adding or removing a lot of entries etc..

When used for a server call, I think the performance of serializing a LinkedList or another implementation (be it using java serialization or any other serialization, like json etc..) are minimal.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I know the difference between  list and  object. I just wanted to know if there are differences in sending a list (arraylist or linked list) or a single object. so, it is only a matter of best performances. thanks again

Comment: Sending a list enables to send you more instances of Person in a single call, that's the difference. Obviously, if you're always sending lists with only one element then you could reconsider using a list.